# Not able to run spoon.bat or any other batch file in Pentaho Data Integration (Kettle)

Tags: java, pentaho, etl, kettle

Tried pdi-ce-4.1.0-stable and pdi-ce-4.2.0-stable

My Machine  - Windows 7 64 bit

When I run Spoon.bat cmd line window appears and disappears and then nothing happens.

When I tried to run it from command line, I get

> DEBUG: Using JAVA_HOME
>   DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_22
>   DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_22\bin\javaw
>
> C:\pentaho\data-integration>start "Spoon" "C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_22\bin \javaw" "-Xmx512m" "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
>   "-Djava.library.path=libswt\win64" "-D KETTLE_HOME="
>   "-DKETTLE_REPOSITORY=" "-DKETTLE_USER=" "-DKETTLE_PASSWORD=" "-DKE
>   TTLE_PLUGIN_PACKAGES=" "-DKETTLE_LOG_SIZE_LIMIT=" -jar
>   launcher\launcher.jar -li b ..\libswt\win64

But then again the PDI GUI doesn't open. I have run the same on another 32 bit machine and it runs perfectly.

Comment: Try it without the "start" command at the front of the line. Then you should see the actual error.  Suspect it's getting confused about 32/64 bit....  Oh; Also you have a space between bin and \javaw, that can't help!  (your java_home is wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their are few things which are not supportable by jdk which are 1.6 or lower then that, try to download jsk 1.7 and configure it may be your problem will solved, because i faced few errors in the past which are because of lower version of jdk.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old commend, but maybe this can help someone.
you just need to replace all "JAVAW" to "JAVA", inside the .bat file.
It worked for me.
tks.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a few folders missing when downloading community edition vs installing EE. Try to install both, and take the "ui" folder from EE and copy it to the CE folder. Running spoon.bat should work now. This worked for me, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem yesterday with the same message after updating Java 7 Update 55.
Kettle: pdi-ce-5.0.1.A-stable
Windows 7 32 bits

Solved: I set the PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME variable to jr6 and now the spoon.bat opens.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting the problem and for all the hints above. I was using latest version of spoon with an older version of Java. when I ran spoon.bat in command line without the start.. it told me that the class file major.minor version is not supported. I installed latest version of Java (X64) and pointed my JAVA_HOME folder to the new folder and here you go... In my case the folder path was "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111". I copied UI folder too from EE to CE.
If you are using latest version of spoon then use the latest version of Java. I needed to add JAVA_HOME or JAVA_JRE variable pointing to the java's latest version folder on my system.